# Set column names conditionally using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to set column names based on the number of columns.

For example,

```
#iris1 <- iris[,1:4]
if(ncol(iris)==4) colnames(iris) <- c("a","b","c","d")
if(ncol(iris)==5) colnames(iris) <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
```

I am looking for a way to do that using the dplyr pipeline. Something like this:

```
iris1 %>%
  setNames(ifelse(ncol(.)==4,c("a","b","c","d"),c("a","b","c","d","e")))
```

**UPDATE:**
akrun's answer gave me this idea which works for me in this particular use-case.

```
cnames <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
iris1 %>% setNames(cnames[1:ncol(.)])
```

This solution cannot be generalised. Better solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is based on a user input 'n', then we can use `rename_at`

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 4
iris %>%
     rename_at(seq_len(n), ~ letters[seq_len(n)])
```

which can be wrapped into a function

```
rename_fn <- function(dat, n){
           dat %>%
             rename_at(seq_len(n), ~ letters[seq_len(n)])
 }

rename_fn(iris, 4)
rename_fn(iris, 5)
```

---

If it is to change all the columns of the dataset, then an easier option is `set_names`

```
iris %>%
     set_names(cnames[seq_len(ncol(.))])
```

Or in `base R`

```
setNames(iris, cnames[seq_len(ncol(iris))])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename all the columns, you should probably use `rename_all`

```
library(dplyr)
iris1 %>% rename_all(~cnames[seq_along(.)]) %>% head

#    a   b   c   d
#1 5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2
#2 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2
#3 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2
#4 4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2
#5 5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2
#6 5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4
```